# Make a list continuous!

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Take an input list **L** containing positive integers, and insert the least amount of integers into the sequence, so that you make it a continuous one.

#### Example:

```
L = 4 2 6 1
Out: 4 3 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

The input and output formats are optional.

#### Test cases:

```
L = 1
Out: 1

L = 10 4
Out: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4

L = 13 13
Out: 13 13

L = 3 6
Out: 3 4 5 6

L = 4 4 1 1 4 4
Out: 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 4
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)... You know the rules.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is a duplicate but I can't find the challenge…

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73636/repair-the-ranges)

Comment: I tried finding a similar one myself, but I couldn't find any. I thought it would make a nice simple challenge. My favorite language is a bit messy when it comes to creating ranges in both ascending and descending order at the same time.

Comment: @Fatalize I didn't find that one when I searched. I do feel this is different enough, but I don't know how strict the community is when it comes to similar challenges...? I guess there will be some answers that are easily portable though...

Comment: The related one is different enough I feel because the input has the same length as the output, so approaches will be more about substitution rather than insertion.

Comment: Test case: `[4,4,1,1,4,4]`

Comment: @Zgarb added :)

Comment: Darn, it was a duplicate after all... :/ It was hard to find that challenge though... Not many obvious words to search for...

Answer (score 2):

## Builtin

#### Husk:

```
…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDsv///0eb6BjpmOkYxgIA)

I bet this builtin exists in more than one language, so I made this a community wiki, just add in more languages where this is a builtin if you know them!

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
⊆.s₂ᵇ-ᵐ~ṡᵐ∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FXm17xo6amh1vbdR9unVD3cOdCIPWoY/n//9EmOiY6hkAIpGP/RwEA)

It's long and slow but at least it's declarative…

#### Explanation

```
⊆.        ∧       The Input is an ordered subset of the Output
  s₂ᵇ             Take all substring of 2 consecutive elements in the Output
     -ᵐ           Take the subtractions of all those substrings
       ~ṡᵐ        They must all be valid "ṡigns" (i.e 1, 0 or -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 72 bytes

Another approach using `ReplaceAll`.

```
#//.{(p={a___,b_,c_,d___})/;b>c+1->(f={a,b,b-#,c,d}&)@1,p/;b<c-1->f@-1}&
```